# What does this exponential sum evaluate to?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums

We have the following sum

$$S=\sum_{\substack{0<a'\leq k'\\(a',k')=1\\a'\equiv b \bmod q}}e(hl'a'/k').$$ Here, $e(x):=\exp(2\pi i x)$, $h,k',q,a'$ are all natural numbers. We do know that $\gcd(h,l')=\gcd(k',l)=1$ because of the reason that in the original sum in the paper, we had $k$ and $l$ which can be replaced by $k'=k/(k,l)$ and $l'=l/(l,k)$. We also know that $(b,q)=1$.

Hooley uses this notation: $k'= \prod_{p^{\alpha}||k'}p^{\alpha}$ which is just the prime decomposition and $k{''}=\prod_{p^{\alpha}||k^{''}; p\nmid q}p^{\alpha}$ which seems a bit odd (?). After that, he goes on to write $S= \sum_{d|k^{''}}\mu(d)\sum_{\substack{0<a'\leq k^{''}\\a'\equiv 0 \bmod d\\a'\equiv b \bmod (k',q)}}e(hl'a'/k')$. This is probably an attempt to write out the sum multiplied by $\sum_{d|(a',k')}\mu(d)$ to capture the condition $(a',k')=1$, but I don't see the connection with $k''$. The author then claims that $(k'/(k,q),q)=1$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for $S\not = 0$ and that this sum is $\mu\{k'/(k',q)\}e(hl'a'/k')$ where $a'$ is the unique root modulo $k'$ of the equations $a\equiv 0 \bmod k'/(k',q)$ and $a\equiv b \bmod (k,q)$.

My question is : how do we find the condition when $S$ is non-zero and what $S$ can evaluate to?

Source: On the Barban-Davenport-Halberstam Theorem (VIII) by Christopher Hooley, roughly pages 16-17.

Perhaps, the argument is not too involved but I have somehow completely missed it. Thanks!